# Best way to access information about all events near a specific latitude and longitude?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, web-scraping, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

So I've been trying to figure out the best approach to this. I looked into Facebook Events and got some conflicting ideas. It seems like you used to use FQL to get events near a coordinate quite easily but now you should use Facebook Graph API (even though some stuff I've read even said that doesn't work properly either). I was also thinking somehow I could scrape google for events near a specific latitude and longitude, but I'm not sure where I would start with that. I'm using a Node.js + Postgres combination for the backend. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Side Note: I think I'm looking for something like what Serpapi offers in terms of their Google search results scraping, but it's VERY expensive.